# 2.3.4: Update "Custom Layout Update" in Category doesn't work

Tags: magento2, layout, custom

I added the file :- `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_[ID]_name.xml`

Edited the category in the backend to use the Specific Layout (`Catalog->Categories->Design->Custom Layout Update->Select "name"` )
Saved. I get the message "You saved the category."
Clear cache.
Refresh category frontend and category backend, but changes have no effect.
Besides, in the category backend, "Custom Layout Update" appears as "No update". So the change is not saved without any error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably is a known bug, see this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27942

Comment: Please add content if url is invalid then Answer is also invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I use magento 2.3.6 and I got this error when trying to create Custom Layout Update in theme

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_[ID]_name.xml
```

I created a module sequence form Magento_Catalog

```
app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_[ID]_name.xml
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

We have Magento 2.4.1 with a multi site and multi theme configuration and we need a cms custom layout update and the only solution we have found is overriding module: app/code...

I think is the same for categories or products custom layout

In our case:

```
app/code/Vendorname/Magento_Cms/view/frontend/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_cms-url-key_name.xml
```